# Graph theorem(homework)

Tags: graph-theory

This is the theorem
If $G$ is a graph, there are at least $2$ vertices(points ) always have the same degree.

e.g:

I have graph $G$,
$(U,V)$ ,$4$ vertices $(e1,e2,e3,e4)$ ,and $4$ edges.
So the degree we have
$(2,2,2,2)$,

and if i put one vertice ,and obtain new graph or new vertice, and so on the graph always have a same degree ,at least  $2$ ..

How i can proof it with pigeon hole principle or others?
Can you give me a clu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

- This is true only in simple graphs (no loops or multiple edges).
- Consider some connected component and denote its size by $n$.
- There are $n$ vertices, but only $n-1$ possible degrees.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$